# Unirationality over the base field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let us say that a variety $X$ over a field $k$ is unirational if there exists a dominant map $\mathbb{P}^n_k\to X$ and geometrically unirational if $X_{\bar{k}}$ is unirational.

Assume that $k$ is infinite. I am considering a certain $k$-variety $X$, on which a finite group $G$ acts faithfully and generically freely. I know that $X$ is unirational, but the dimension of $X$ is quite large. Let $Y$ be a twist of $X$. Of course, $Y$ is geometrically unirational. I also know that $Y(k)$ is infinite. After failing for a long time to prove unirationality of this $Y$, I am now turning to prove the opposite, i.e. non-unirationality. Are there any general techniques that might work in this setting? In all the cases I know one proves that the variety is not unirational by showing that rational points are not dense, but this is not going to work in this case.

Comment: $k$-unirational implies that $k$-points form a Zariski-dense subset. What do you mean by very few?

Comment: I believe Bixej means to show that a twist is not unirational by showing that rational points are not dense (or even that there are none, e.g. Brauer Severi varieties)

Comment: In general this is very difficult. E.g. any del Pezzo surface of degree $1$ has a rational point, but it is not known whether every such surface is unirational (they are expected to be unirational). It would help if you gave some more specific details about the variety you have in mind.

Comment: Also, at least over a number field $k$, your suggested approach to show non-unirationality won't work. Any smooth project (geometrically) rationally connected variety over a number field $k$ with a rational point is conjectured to have a Zariski dense set of rational points (see "weak weak approximation" on wikipedia).